# Calculation of $\sum xf(x)$ given $\sum f(x)$?

Tags: summation, expected-value, variance

Given the sum $\sum f(x)$, is it possible to calculate $\sum xf(x)$? What if it is constrained that these are infinite sums? I assume that this doesn't exist because then computing variance would be very easy, and I've heard that it isn't.

Comment: No, it is not possible in general

Comment: For each given $x\in X$, the value $f(x)$ is unknown, hence can be treated as a 'variable'. Then the condition $\sum_{x\in X} f(x)=c$ only reduces the degree of freedom by $1$, which is by no means enough to determine all the values of $f(x)$'s unless $|X|=1$.

Comment: Any nontrivial examples of when this would be possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given $f(1)+f(2)$ is it possible to compute $f(1)+2f(2)$?  Even then, the answer is "no".

Another example.  A discrete probability distribution satisfies $\sum f(x) = 1$. The expectation of that distribution is $\sum x f(x)$.  But of course not all discrete probability distributions have the same expectation.

Comment: Any nontrivial examples of when this would be possible?